# Core Data One to Many Relationship: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am having two classes or objects: `User` and `Medicine`. Here is my `User` class:

```
@interface User : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *medicine;
@end

@interface User (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addMedicineObject:(Medicine *)value;
- (void)removeMedicineObject:(Medicine *)value;
- (void)addMedicine:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeMedicine:(NSSet *)values;
@end
```

and then the `Medicine` class

```
@interface Medicine : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * medName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * medType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Dose *dose;
@property (nonatomic, retain) User *user;

@end
```

As my interfaces clearly show that user may have multiple medicines. (I am from database background thats why I am interpreting it like this).

When I add new object in `User`, it is easily done, but when I try to add new `Medicine` for existing object of user, I feel that my Xcode has a deep wish to shoot me at that time (vice versa).

Now here is the code that describes what I am doing:

```
Medicine *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
User *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
if(![self checkUser])
{
    object.user = user;
    [user setName:self.userName];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@",object, user);
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
}
else
{
    Medicine *medicine = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Medicine" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    user = [self getUser:self.userName];
    medicine.medName = object.medName;
    medicine.medType = object.medType;
    [medicine setUser:user];
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = medicine;
}
```

I am having a simple logic: if name entered by user in text field, already exist in DB, then return the `User` object. Then just add another `Medicine` record for the same `User`. Other wise add new `User` and a `Medicine` object as well.

but I get error at:

```
[medicine setUser:user];
```

I also tried this one: (as I got it in another question like mine)

```
[user addMedicineObject:medicine];
```

Now I think that I have to override `addMedicineObject` method or something else.

Oh I forgot the error. I get this error: (the real villain)

```
[__NSArrayM managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8136bf0
```

Now any suggestion?

Comment: You are sending a `managedObjectContext` message to an array. Are you sure the model has been set up correctly? Are you using a third part lib?

Comment: I am not using any third party lib. Purely CoreData. In my model i am having one to many relation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you trying to mutate `NSSet` object. You need to create a mutable copy before you edit it.

Comment: Oops i forgot to mention that I am having a mutable copy of User Object while trying to edit. Do I have to make mutable for medicine as well?

Comment: The things which are being changed should have mutable copy.

Comment: well my bad luck. I have made them mutable already but still same error.